# Datatype for a column with both numbers and text in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis

I am exporting data from Excel to a SQL Server table using SSIS. I have a column in Excel which contains numbers and text.

What is the best datatype that I could use in the created table in SQL Server for this column to make the export of data smooth?

The reason that I am asking this is because I tried the data transformation and only the data with numbers in the above mentioned column got loaded properly.

BTW I used `nvarchar(255)` for the above column.

Thank you

Edit: My table kind of looks like this

[image]

The rows with text in col3 and col4 are not copied into the table

Comment: nvarchar is fine.  You must have done something else wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If your excel column contains combined values of characters, numbers and alphanumeric, add **IMEX=1** to the extended properties of excel connection manager.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3d-XIYuB7k

Thanks